# Linq get all fields from select along with dynamic column

Tags: linq

I have such Linq, I would like to get all records from Orders table and also add new dynamic field. The code below do not work. What is correct syntax?

```
user.dcOrders.Select(p =>p, new { FullName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to list out all the columns.

Alternatively you could add a new property to whatever class `dcOrders` is.  It should be specified as a `partial class` so you can add the `FullName` property to a new file so it doesn't get overwritten when the `.designer.cs` file is regenerated.

So something like

```
public partial class Orders
{
    public string FullName { get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; } }
}
```

Be sure to add this to a separate file not the `.designer.cs` file. (I'm assuming LINQ to SQL here).

Then you don't need to do any special select, because `FullName` will already exist as a property on the object.  You can just use it directly.

Comment: Could you show me how to get all columns along with dynamic one?

Comment: @Tomas for the first option you'll actually need to type out every column.  The 2nd option might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var names = user.dcOrders.Select(p => new { 
                                              User = p,
                                              FullName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName 
                                          });
```

Comment: I want to list all columns and not only dynamic.